# merge two excel lists with different data

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have two excel files which is a customer lists, the first one listing our customers transactions, and the second one listing the customers failed transactions, how can I add the failed transaction column to the first file to have the total number of transactions in one column and the failed transaction in another column.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is called a "pivot table".

EDIT :
Once you know this is named a pivot table, it becomes trivial.

```
0. Merge your two sheets on the same page
1.  "insert -> pivot table", select all lines.
2. Add the user identification in "lines" part of the pivot
3. Add anything that identificates the transaction in the "values"
4. Set the "count" in values type.
5. Select the "missed transaction", add it to values.
6. Find the "sum" logo which is wether in "columns" or "lines" and put it to columns.
```